# Is there a way to get a movie clip to identify itself in AS2?

Tags: flash, movieclip, actionscript-2

Basically, I'm making a very simple turn based battle game using ActionScript 2.0.

I'm VERY new to code, with only very limited Visual Basic knowledge, so I'll happily admit I don't really know what I'm doing. I've got a start, but I decided to rewrite the entire thing because I wouldn't be able to cycle enemies and levels easily.

I've spawned the same enemy twice `using _root.attachMovie`, and identified them as Enemy1 and Enemy2. After spawning them, I tried to make them identify themselves with:

```
_root.Enemy1.identify = "Enemy1"
_root.Enemy1.identify = "Enemy1"
```

Using the debugger, this apparently works (within the movieclip, they have a variable called identify which correctly labels them), yet when I try to use an if statement so I can put them in their own individual positions, it simply does not work; it skims straight over. The code I have within the movie clips is:

```
if (identify == "Enemy1") {

    function poschange() {

        _root.Enemy1._x = _root.Enemy1.POSX;

        _root.Enemy1._y = _root.Enemy1.POSY;

        _root.Enemy1.swapDepths(_root.Enemy1.POSY);

    }

} else if (identify == "Enemy2") {

    function poschange() {

        _root.Enemy2._x = _root.Enemy2.POSX;

        _root.Enemy2._y = _root.Enemy2.POSY;

        _root.Enemy2.swapDepths(_root.Enemy2.POSY);

    }

}

poschange();
```

The poschange functions works fine for the player characters, it's just this if statement to identify which enemy it is apparently fails.

So my question is: is there any easier way for a movie clip to identify its own ID so I don't have to use this method, or is there just something wrong with my code?